# how to pull image based on architecture with bazel

Tags: docker, architecture, arm, x86-64, bazel

i'm running bazel and using rule `container_pull` of `rules_docker`.
`container_pull` has an architecture attribute.
In CI and some dev machines, the architecture is amd.
In new m1 macs, the architecture is arm.

How do I configure bazel to pull amd on amd machines and arm on arm machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is with two container_pull rules and [select](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/functions.html#select). In your `WORKSPACE`:

```py
container_pull(
    name = "thing_amd",
    architecture = "amd64",
    <same stuff you have now>
)

container_pull(
    name = "thing_arm",
    architecture = "arm",
    <same stuff you have now>
)
```

And then in some `BUILD` file:

```py
config_setting(
    name = "k8",
    constraint_values = ["@platforms//cpu:x86_64"],
)

config_setting(
    name = "arm",
    constraint_values = ["@platforms//cpu:arm"],
)

alias(
    name = "thing",
    actual = select({
        ":k8": "@thing_amd//image",
        ":arm": "@thing_arm//image",
    }),
)
```

If you want to deduplicate (especially if you have more than two CPUs), [macros](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/macros.html) are helpful. Create a `.bzl` file with all the CPUs in a variable, and then a macro to create all the `container_pull` repositories (that you load+call from `WORKSPACE`) and another macro to create the `config_setting`s and the `alias` that you load+call from that `BUILD` file.

Comment: great answer :) i'm surprised more people haven't struggled with this / upvoted this